# Made With Love in (somewhere) / Coded With (heart symbol) by (somebody) trend

Tags: copywriting, footers

In footers everywhere I'm seeing those lines that say "Made with love in San Francisco" or "Coded with (heart symbol) in New York", or some other variation.  They seem to be really popular.  My question is -- why?  How did this trend come about, what purpose does it serve UX-wise, and should it be part of the UX on my site?

(Here's an example, somebody even made a NPM package for this: http://jugoncalv.es/heart/)

Comment: I think Apple somewhat pioneered this with printing “Designed in California” on its product packages, which is shown more prominently than the more or less mandatory “Made in China” or “Assembled in Taiwan”. I don’t know who first added “with love” or “with pride” to this, but there’re also variants that substitute the location with a tool, e.g. “on a Mac” or “with Linux” and it is a small step from there to “with love”.

Comment: This isn't a UX question. This is just a Marketing/Copywriting thing.

Comment: @Crissov the "made with love" phrase probably was pioneered by some grandma's selling pies by the road 100 years ago.

Comment: @Crissov I hadn't thought about Apple's "Designed in California" statement... that's an excellent point.

Comment: re: put on hold ... isn't UX primarily opinion based to begin with?  It's not like programming where there are "right" answers (i.e. code either works or doesn't).... UX deals with human beings, so at best we can only gather the OPINIONS of other expert human beings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of these sentences is to build **TRUST** and to feel **PERSONAL**

Additionally there is the movement of being proud that a product was created in your country as a form of nationalism and content that the thing you are going to use/purchase created jobs and boosted the economy of your own country. Nothing more useable about it tho,besides maybe being connected to more sales or users it has no effect on the conceived product

Answer (score 0):

Think it's a variation of how the country of origin is engraved at the back of electronics and other various products. 


E.g. "made in China" 

Except in our age a web based or software product might be built across multiple countries. Maybe it's conceptualised in the US, developed in India. So you can't exactly say it was made in a certain country. UX wise I don't think it adds much except adding a good feeling.

Answer (score 0):

UX wise "Made in/with somewhere/something" can definitely add a "personal" touch to your site. However the relevance is completely governed by the sort of project your working on. I see it working everywhere from Apple to coffee shops and you could make it work for yourself, too.